# Allow all file extensions on php upload script

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload

So I am using a raspberry pi and want to use it as a place where I can upload and download any kind of file with any kind of extension.

Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my php

```
<?php  
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_error = $file['error'];

    $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    $allowed = array('txt', 'jpg');

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {
        if($file_error === 0) {
            if($file_size <= 1073741824) {

                $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                $file_destination = 'files/' . $file_name_new;

                if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
                    echo $file_destination;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works great but only lets me upload .txt and .jpg files. I tried removing the "$allowed" thing all together but broke the script.

Any ideas?

Comment: if you simply remove the `if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed))`, it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change code to this :

```
    if($file_error === 0) {
        if($file_size <= 1073741824) {

            $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
            $file_destination = 'files/' . $file_name_new;

            if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
                echo $file_destination;
            }
        }
    }
```